# Selecting multiple values from a string in ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, definition-query, string

[image]I have a text field containing values like `"1A,2P,13,17,22,34"`.

I want to select the values that I need by a definition query of a layer.

For a single value worked using `LIKE` and `%` but I **need to select up to 3 values** that will be used for defining my layer. How is it possible?

I am working on ArcGIS Desktop.

Comment: field like 'template string 1' and field like 'template string 2' and field like 'template string 3'?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  What GIS software are you using?  I recommend always saying that early in your question body.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question that you can use to add it now, and other details at any time.

Comment: @Mircea Angelescu, which software do you use?

Comment: @Taras - ArcMap

Comment: Can you give a screenshot of that field///fieds?

Comment: JuniorPythonNewbie - Of course - just to know how I can attach it

Comment: @JuniorPythonNewbie - I have tried to simplify and I gave numerical codes to the values of the field "Nivel". Now, the field I'm trying to query is called Cod_Niv. And you are right about using the placeholder %. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

That will depend on if you have unique value for a record or not.

if you have only one value per record use the IN operator :

```
yourfield IN ('value1', 'value2', ...)
```

note that text value are between quote, numeric value don't need quote

if your field hold several value, use several LIKE operator linked with OR

```
yourfielf LIKE '%value1%' OR yourfielf LIKE '%value2%' OR ....
```

Be crrefull with the `%` placeholder to not select unwanted value, for exemple `yourfielf LIKE '%A1%'` will select for record with A1 but also A12 OR AA1

Also the exact syntax (field name with double quote or braquet..) may depend on the data source type you use